# Ember JS, Error while parsing Data in Transformer handeling event `didCommit` in state root.loaded.updated.uncommitted."

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, transformer-model

I am getting an error in an Ember Transformer trying a parse a date in the serialize function.

Error message:
"Attempted to handle event `didCommit` on <(subclass of DS.Model):ember1597:8260357> while in state root.loaded.updated.uncommitted."

Strangely enough, the data is transmitted correctly parsed to the server.

Code:

```
DS.Transform.extend({

    deserialize : function(serialized) {

        var array = [];

        if (Ember.isArray(serialized)) {

            serialized.forEach(function(item) {
                if (item.feldTyp === "DATE_FIELD" && item.value) {
                    Ember.set(item, "value", moment(item.value, "DD.MM.YYYY"));
                }
                array.addObject(Ember.Object.create(item));
            });
        }

        return array;
    },

    serialize : function(deserialized) {
        if (Ember.isArray(deserialized)) {
            deserialized.forEach(function(item) {
                if (item.get('feldTyp') === "DATE_FIELD" && item.get('value')) {
                    item.set('value', moment(item.get('value')).format("DD.MM.YYYY"));
                }
            });
            return deserialized;
        }

        return [];
    }
});
```

The line `item.set('value', moment(item.get('value')).format("DD.MM.YYYY"));` causes the error as commented out the error vanishes.  I tried other things like setting a static value or setting the value using `Ember.set` but without success. I do not quite know what went wrong here and thus cannot think of a solution. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

*edit*

Workaround:
I moved the serialization into the controller. Does not look as elegant but works for now...

Answer (score 1):

As you've figured out ember data doesn't like the use of `set` in its transforms. Because the server representation of data is often different from how it is represented on the client side. Ember expects transforms to not modify the `serialized` or `deserialized` values that are passed in and instead to return new values.

The reason this error is happening is because ember has a state machine to track the state of a record in relation to the server (see http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RootState.html). In this case ember is most likely putting the record into the `inFlight` state. It then calls the transform's serialize function. When `item.set` is called ember notices a change to the record and inadvertently transitions the record back into the `uncommitted` state. After the server responds to the save request ember mistakenly assuming the record is still in the `inFlight` state signals the `didCommit` event so the record can transition to the `saved` state. Because the `uncommitted` state doesn't support the `didCommit` event ember throws an error.

I suspect you could fix this issue by rewriting your serialize function to not call `set` and instead to return a new array.

```
    serialize : function(deserialized) {
        if (Ember.isArray(deserialized)) {
            return deserialized.map(function(item) {
                if (item.get('feldTyp') === "DATE_FIELD" && item.get('value')) {
                    return moment(item.get('value')).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
                }
            });
        }

        return [];
    }
```